# store multiple date ranges in solr field

Tags: database, solr

Every day I check which events happened. Each event is represented as a document in Solr index.
An event can happen 4 days in a row, skips a day and then happen the next 4 days and so on... In a typical search query, I need to find all events that happened between start date and end date and also return the date ranges of event occurrence.

[image]

In the image above, a search between 1. and 17. would return R1(1-4), R2(6-9) and R3(11-14)

How do you store multiple date ranges in indexed and stored solr field?

Comment: Solr has a DateRangeField that lets you store date ranges. However, in your example it seems like you don't have a range actually stored, but need to calculate it (which you could then store in a second set of documents). That would be a task for your own application (or you could possibly implementing something in streaming expressions, but I haven't tested that)